# Populate HTML Table having javascript variable and than return that HTML variable as a typeahead result

Tags: javascript, html, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead on an input to send suggestions.. every thing work fine but know i want to create HTML table dynamically and assign values in a table so in my java script I declare HTML variable to store the table and than i'm using this variable when i return values. The problem arose when I save the html in a variable than It starting giving error that my the variable is not defined and when I put it in quotes than on return it just shows me the variable. .. I don't know what to do or which methodology should I've to use but I'm stuck at that Point here is my HTML working

```
 <input class="typeahead" placeholder="Enter to Search" />
```

Here is my javascript working

```
 var jsonData = [{
country: "Holland",
city: "Amsterdam"
}, {
country: "Belgium",
city: "Brussel"
}, {
country: "Germany",
city: "Berlin"
}, {
country: "France",
    "city": "Paris"
}];

var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('country', 'city'),
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: jsonData

});

dataSource.initialize();
var html='<div><table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="50%" align="right">\'+data.country+\'</td><td width="50%">' + 'data.city' + '</td></tr></table></div>';

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
minLength: 1,
highlight: true
}, {
name: 'countries',
display: function(item){ return item.country+'–'+item.city},
source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
templates: {
    empty: [
        '<div class="empty">No Matches Found</div>'].join('\n'),
            header: '<div><h5><table width="100%" border="1"><thead><tr><th width="50%" align="center">Item Name</th><th width="50%" align="center">City Name</td></th></table></h5></div>', 
    suggestion: function (data) {
        return html
    }
  }
  });
```

Here is my Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agrg3xhj/333/) link

Any Suggestion ...  ? ? ?

### Update 1

Now I'm able to generate HTML dynamically .. . with the help of your suggestions.
So now I'm up to generate array keys dynamically in my updated fiddle but the problem is when i generate dynamically than it gives me undefined result and when I hard code the array key than It return me the true values which are required Take a look at my  **[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59b62kz3/9/)** below is my javascript code

```
 var jsonData = [{ 
 a: "Holland",
b: "Amsterdam"
}, {
a: "Holland",
b: "Amsterdam"
}, {
a: "Holland",
b: "Amsterdam"
}, {
a: "Holland",
b: "Amsterdam"
}, {
a: "Belgium",
b: "Brussel"
}, {
a: "Germany",
b: "Berlin"
}, {
a: "France",
b: "Paris"
}];

 var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('a', 'b'),
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
local: jsonData

 });

dataSource.initialize();

var generateHTML= function(data) {
var key='a';
var html='<div><table width="100%" border="1"><tr>';
for(var i=0; i<2; i++)
{
html+='<td width="50%" align="right">' + data. key + '</td>';
  //key++;
}
//'<td width="50%">' + data.city + '</td></tr></table></div>';
html+='</tr></table></div>';
return html;
//return '<div><table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="50%" align="right">' + data.country + '</td><td width="50%">' + data.city + '</td></tr></table></div>'
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
minLength: 1,
highlight: true
}, {
name: 'countries',
display: function(item){ return item.country+'–'+item.city},
source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
templates: {
    empty: [
        '<div class="empty">No Matches Found</div>'].join('\n'),
            header: '<div><h5><table width="100%" border="1"><thead>    <tr><th width="50%" align="center">Item Name</th><th width="50%" align="center">City Name</td></th></table></h5></div>', 
    suggestion: function (data) {
        return generateHTML(data)
    }
  }
  });
```

### Update 3 Task Done by Doing RND on Javascript Array Objects

Thank You All for your Help and Suggestions. I'm able to do it Successfully. When we call Java Script arrays by objects than we have to pass our dynamically generated keys in the following pattern

```
 obj[key];
```

following is my working  [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/59b62kz3/37/)

Answer (score 2):

As your HTML is out of the scope of the function `suggestion` the variable `html` can't see the variable called `data`.

One way to solve this would be creating a function which takes as parameter the data variable and then returns to you an HTML with the data on it.

```
var generateHTML= function(data) {
    return '<div><table width="100%" border="1"><tr><td width="50%" align="right">' + data.country + '</td><td width="50%">' + data.city + '</td></tr></table></div>'
};
```

And then call this function on the `suggestion` function:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true
}, {
    name: 'countries',
    display: function(item){ return item.country+'–'+item.city},
    source: dataSource.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        empty: [
            '<div class="empty">No Matches Found</div>'].join('\n'),
                header: '<div><h5><table width="100%" border="1"><thead><tr><th width="50%" align="center">Item Name</th><th width="50%" align="center">City Name</td></th></table></h5></div>', 
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return generateHTML(data)
        }
    }
});
```

Here is an example of how this could be done: http://jsfiddle.net/59b62kz3/

Comment: yes it worked know check again when i generate key dynamically than it gives me undefined data and when I define then key name of the column than it work fine herre is my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59b62kz3/9/)